# Prove a inequality with positive numbers

Tags: calculus, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ positive real numbers. Moreover, let $C>0.$ I have the following inequality,
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 \leq Cab + c.
\end{equation}
My goal is to absorb the numbers $a,b$ which are on the right hand side with those on the left hand side, in order to prove the following inequality,
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 < \tilde{C}c,
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{C}>0$ is a constant.

My try. I use the Cauchy Schwartz with $\epsilon >0,$ and then I have
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 \leq \epsilon Ca^2 + \frac{1}{4\epsilon}b^2 + c.
\end{equation}
Now, I can choose sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ in order to absorb $\alpha.$ Can I somehow absorb the $b?$

Answer (score 1):

You have$$a^2 + b^2 \leq Cab + c = \frac{C}{2}\left(a^2+b^2 - (a-b)^2\right)+c \leq \frac{C}{2}(a^2+b^2 )+c $$

so $$\left(1- \frac{C}{2} \right)(a^2+b^2) \leq c$$

and finally, if $C< 2$, $$a^2+b^2 \leq \frac{2c}{2-C}$$

Comment: Notice that your constant in the right hand side is negative for $C>2.$ So, your solution holds only for $C < 2.$